# Pandas Series SettingWithCopyWarning following caveats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Im desperate with this warning. I'm doing the following:

```
groups = df.groupby('year')
2018_group = groups.get_group('2018')

if not 2018_group['Descripcion'].empty:
    desc = 2018_group.loc[2018_group['Descripcion'].notnull(), 'Desc'].copy()
    2018_group.loc[:, 'Descripcion'] = desc.unique()[0]
    print 2018_group
```

Getting the known error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  2018_group.loc['Desc'] = desc.unique()[0]
```

What I want to do is fill the column 'Desc' with the non-empty value in that column

Comment: @Idlehands I've checked that post without success doing exactly the same and also reading docs... that's the reason I'm asking now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is earlier in your code: `2018_group` represents a slice of your dataframe.

So copy the slice *before* modifying it:

```
2018_group = groups.get_group('2018').copy()
```

As an aside, you make a `copy` in your definition of `desc` for no visible purpose.